# System requirements for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, system-requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for system specifications for a modern GIS workstation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/looking-for-system-specifications-for-a-modern-gis-workstation)

I have been using the program to make maps to include in my reports over the past year or so. It is excellent. However, my computer seems to not be able to handle all the data sometimes, and the program crashes. It happens when I do too much editing to data points that I have manipulated.

My question is what system requirements are recommended to run this program with a lot of data points? Or does it simply depend on what I want to do with the program? I am probably going to get a faster computer primarily based on wanting to use this program.

Comment: memory memory memory.

Comment: It's either a problem with your computer, or your data storage / retrieval methods. Post your RAM / HD / Processor / Graphics card and the type / size / number of records / number of columns of the data you're working with.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have 4 GB (2.86 GB usable) / 100 GB of 453 GB free / Intel Core i3 350M @ 2.27 GHz / Intel HD graphics chip / Not sure of size / some of the layers I am working with are polygons and have 700-800 features with 20 columns, one layer has 5000 features with 5 columns. My current laptop is a Portege R700, and it is 32 bit. That could be part of my issue. I am considering buying a Toshiba Satellite P750-13N.